# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options. The provideres are incorrect

Tags: angular, firebase, angular17

This is the error:
`R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_TarjetaService -> _TarjetaService -> _AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!`

I have this error, I am using angular 17 and standalone on true (i dont have app.module.ts), I've had these same supplier problems before.
I proceed to show part of the code:

*app.config.ts:*

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), 
    provideClientHydration(), 
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({
      //here i have my configuration
    }))), 
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())), 
    importProvidersFrom(provideStorage(() => getStorage())),
  ]
};
```

I set these providers to Firebase when installing it

*app.component.ts:*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ListarTarjetaComponent } from './components/listar-tarjeta/listar-tarjeta.component';
import { CrearTarjetaComponent } from './components/crear-tarjeta/crear-tarjeta.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet,
    ListarTarjetaComponent,
    CrearTarjetaComponent,
    AngularFireModule,
    ToastrModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tarjetacreditoangular';
}
```

*tarjeta.service.ts:*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { TarjetaCredito } from '../models/tarjeta-credito/tarjeta-credito.module';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TarjetaService {

  private tarjeta$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

  guardarTarjeta(tarjeta: TarjetaCredito): Promise<any> {
    return this.firestore.collection('tarjetas').add(tarjeta);
  }

  obtenerTarjetas(): Observable<any> {
    return this.firestore.collection('tarjetas', ref => ref.orderBy('fechaCreacion', 'asc')).snapshotChanges();
  }

  eliminarTarjeta(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.firestore.collection('tarjetas').doc(id).delete();
  }

  editarTarjeta(id: string, tarjeta: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.firestore.collection('tarjetas').doc(id).update(tarjeta);
  }

  addTarjetaEdit(tarjeta: TarjetaCredito) {
    this.tarjeta$.next(tarjeta);
  }

  getTarjetaEdit(): Observable<TarjetaCredito> {
    return this.tarjeta$.asObservable();
  }

}
```

When I installed firebase in my project, the environments folder was not created. Also

I tried importing several modules, modifying the providers but I always get the same result